# Opencart 3 products not fetch data mysql query not showing products

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart-3

I have this query but it's not showing any data, I'm getting blank results:

```
SELECT * FROM oc_product p
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
WHERE pd.language_id = '1'
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY pd.name ASC
```

I think the problem is in the `oc_product_description` table (field descriptions).

I try also  `SELECT * FROM oc_product` This working fine, but `SELECT * FROM oc_product_description` this not working , `SELECT name FROM oc_product_description` this working fine ...

**This is my full code**

```
<?php
// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'opencart');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');


$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo 'Database connection failed with following errors: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
  die();
}


$products = [];
//$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ". DB_PREFIX ."product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON pd.product_id = p.product_id WHERE pd.language_id = 1");

$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_product p LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '1' GROUP BY p.product_id ORDER BY pd.name ASC");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $products[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($products);

?>
```

please help me  anyone...thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you either don't have any matching row for that products in `oc_product_description` or that the descriptions you have in that table for those products have a value in `language_id` different of `1`.

Although you are using `LEFT JOIN` for joining the description your `WHERE` condition is using a column of the table `oc_product_description`, which is the equivalent of converting it to an `INNER JOIN`, because the results for all the products without a matching description will have a `NULL` value for `language_id`, so the condition `WHERE pd.language_id = 1` would be always false.

Check the contents of your description table, also you can rewrite the query in this way to return results also for products without description:

```
SELECT p.*, IFNULL(pd.name,'(no description found)') as name
FROM oc_product p
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id AND pd.language_id = 1
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY pd.name ASC
```

This works because we moved the condition to the `LEFT JOIN` so if the condition fails it only affects the join.

Note that if the products table has a column with a default description you could use that column instead of `'(no description found)'`.